# Joomla! <base href...> is wrong

Tags: php, joomla

I have locally downloaded a running system with Joomla! 1.5.22, my new job, from a production server. Now I cannot find the place to change the Base URL. I already fiddled around with the `JURI` class in `uri.php`, but to no avail.
Then I deleted all the entries from `SH404sef`and the canonicalization is off.
Has anybody got an idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, upgrade to 1.5.26 immediately, 1.5.26j if you can get your hands on it.
1.5.26 has publicly - disclosed security vulnerabilities which were not fixed.

Edit your configuration.php in the root, that should contain the basic installation path.

Disable the sh404 plugins and (after you upgrade to at least 1.5.26) you should get it working (currently there may be hacks that prevent it from working).

Make sure your system-SEF plugin is enabled if using SEF otherwise the image paths will be wrong.

Comment: Thanks, how is that upgrading done? Is there any risk on the system? It has many plugins. I would like to switch sh404 off, but to get into the administration area is a matter of luck, usually it just stucks with the session cookie set and it keeps loading, loading, the login mask is still on display...any comment for that? Can we have a chat somewhere due to your knowlegeable comments? Regards!! Skype would be nice, to have somebody to ask if something goes wrong. ;)

Comment: You will find detailed instructions on getting upgrades here - http://docs.joomla.org/Upgrading_1.5_from_an_existing_1.5x_version , that will also have a link to download 1.5.26 upgrade patch. To simplify migration process between servers use Akeeba Backup extension to back up the site on its original location and Akeeba Kickstart script to restore it on the new server.  Akeeba is free and very powerful, it will automatically re-map your base directory and other settings during restore.
Good luck.

Comment: @InsiderPro Any comments on the administration area login issue? Thanks!!

Comment: It was SEF which made the wrong `BASE`. I will talk to the chief if he wants to take the perils of updating against the security risk. ;) I still have issues with the administrator login, but I can "login", then the ball of death comes, then I just navigate to an inside-administrator URL, then it works. Thanks all!! :)